Unable to turn on (toggle) the bluetooth on Ubuntu 24.04
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-20 06:26:04 CEST; 15min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1188 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 27851)
     Memory: 2.7M (peak: 3.2M)
        CPU: 37ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1188 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

uname -r
6.9.3-060903-generic


sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[    3.014450] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.014522] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.014526] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.014537] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.014543] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.014554] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.497308] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.497315] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.497322] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.096409] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110


Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:012d TP-Link Archer T3U [Realtek RTL8812BU]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3277:0036 ShineTech USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
[sudo] password for fracazzo: 
[    0.294275] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.477705] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 127...
[    1.661389] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    1.661424] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    1.661427] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.661436] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.661440] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.661447] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.955891] rtw_8822bu 1-1:1.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    3.533061] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x08003700
[    3.533427] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.19 DEC: 7 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    3.533435] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    3.715490] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.715496] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.715503] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.753548] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[ 1290.890052] rtw_8822bu 1-1:1.0: firmware failed to leave lps state



Mainstream:
6.8.0-38.38_24.04 Installed (with ubuntu logo)
6.8.0-38.38 Installed (with ubuntu logo)
6.9.r Running 


This is all I tried unseccessfully:


sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-5.19
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
killall pulseaudio
systemctl unmask bluetooth.service
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools


sudo hciconfig -a hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

Any suggestion? Thank you

Two things. In the first part of the question it says the Bluetooth service is running. Second where did the 6.9 kernel come from?

Please edit the question to include results for lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Nevermind, found your month old question about your wifi- neither wifi or bluetooth is supported in Linux yet for the MT7902

$ uname -r -> 6.8.0-38-generic on Ubuntu 24.04 ... I'd suggest you either go back to standard 6.8 series kernel or turn your questions towards linux kernel development areas / groups / communities.

Hi, as requested see below

Found a solution on another forum - installing a custom bluetooth driver will help, but i notice that your kernel version is 6.9.x
jeremyb31 has bluetooth drivers for Ubuntu v6.8 kernel on his git repository, so if you revert to v6.8 this may work:
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.8
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
Reboot

